# Can't send data from ajax call to php to get database value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I've a problem to retrieve my data from database.

In my Ajax call, i have tested my form values and it worked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var color = $('#Color').val();
    var radio = $('input[name="filter_opties"]:checked').val();
    filter(color, radio);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "db_querys.php",
        data: {'color' : color, 'radio' : radio},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

But in my db_querys.php, I can't get the values of color and radio.

```
<?php
$gekozenGemeente = $_POST['color'];
$gekozenCategorie = $_POST['radio']; 

if($gekozenGemeente != null)
  {
  echo $gekozenGemeente . $gekozenCategorie;
  }
else
  {
  echo "<br> Values are null";
  }
?>
```

This is my form:

```
<form id = "form" action="#" method="post" >
    <!----- Select Option Fields Starts Here ----->
    <label class="heading">Selecteer uw gemeente:</label>
    <br>
    <select name="Color" id="Color">
        <option value="heemstede">Heemstede</option>
        <option value="bloemendaal">Bloemendaal</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <!---- Radio Button Starts Here ----->
    <label class="heading">Radio Buttons :</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="filter_opties" value="Betaald"><label for="radio1">Betaald</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="filter_opties" value="Vergunning"><label for="radio2">Vergunning</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="filter_opties" value="Blauwe zone"><label for="radio3">Blauwe zone</label><br/>
    <br>
    <input id= "submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Get Selected Values" onclick="filter()">
</form>
```

Can you guys explain what I'm missing?

**EDIT:     Added the filter function.**

```
function filter(color, radio){

    var locations = <?= json_encode($markers_json ); ?>;
    var locations2 = JSON.parse(locations);


    var polygons = <?=json_encode($polygons_json );?>;
    //var polygons2 = JSON.parse(polygons);
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = polygons2;


    initialize(locations2,polygons)

      }
```

Comment: php and html both tags for this?

Comment: where is onclick="filter()" function ??

Comment: @geminiousgoel, That are the stuff that I use

Comment: @SurajKhanra I've added the filter() function

Comment: should tag to which your problem belongs not to all keywords that you used. In that way to will tag "radio", "button", "form", "class"...?

Comment: @geminiousgoel, thanks for your feedback. I will change it.

Comment: Why are you mixing up php code with javascript in your filter function?

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var color = $('#Color').val();
    var radio = $('input[name="filter_opties"]:checked').val();
    filter(color, radio);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "db_querys.php",
        data: {'color' : color, 'radio' : radio},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell what your code is doing, or what the difference is.  In your case you replaced `$("form#form")` with `$("#form")` Please add some explanation, without that, your answer is pretty much useless.